# typecasting error in 64 bit. type mismatch

Tags: vb6, type-mismatch

I am having problem in deploying VB6 apps into 64 bit windows. When I run the EXE, It gives out error "type mismatch"

The code is below :

```
Private Sub writedate (loc as string)
    Dim dout(0 To 15) As Byte
    Dim strdate_day as string
    Dim strdate_mon as string
:
:
dout(0) = strdate_day 'This is the problem in 64 bit
dout(1) = strdate_mon 

End sub 

Public Function **Hex_Dec2**(ByVal val As String, ByVal start As Byte) As Byte
Dim MSB As Byte
Dim LSB As Byte
Dim Fbyte As Byte

              Fbyte = 0
              MSB = 0
              LSB = 0

              MSB = StrHEX_Dec(Mid(val, start, 1))
              LSB = StrHEX_Dec(Mid(val, start + 1, 1))
              Fbyte = (MSB * 16) + LSB

Hex_Dec2 = Fbyte
Debug.Print "val : " & val & " Fbyte : " & Fbyte
End Function
```

If I run the EXE file on 32 bit machine, it works fine. Absolutely no error.

The code HEX_DEC2 is a special function that converts string into byte. **I have to use this function** otherwise the value written will be incorrect. When I do : `dout(0) = HEX_DEC2(strdate_day)`, it does not give "type mismatch" error on 64bit. For technical reason, i don't want to run this function

Strangely, the laptop that I am using to develop the app is 64 bit as well and doesn't give out any error when i run it from both the source code and the EXE file.

How do i overcome this problem ?

Comment: thats really strange - vb6 runs always as 32bit. but anyway: can you please explain what your code should do? It seems to me you writing some strange values to a byte array, are you?

Comment: Iam trying to write a date value into an rfid card. It actually writes the value in byte. But, to shortcut the process, i skipped the hex_dec2 function. It doesnt give out error when run in 32 bit windows. It seems the 64 bit can not ignore the type difference. Any clue is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are rely on an automatic type cast ... this is not really a shortcut, but a source of strange behaviours - as you see in this case. So my advise: do not use this "shortcut". This convert function looks very complex for an easy task: How should the value 30th May 2018 be represented in the byte array?

Comment: Dont know how it should look like. I just use the function for granted.

Comment: 310518 is converted into 318018. When i skip the hexdec funct, it writes the date correctly into the card.

Comment: Which is the exact line where the error occurs?

Comment: never mind @DaveInCaz. The error is on the "dout(0) = HEX_DEC2(strdate_day)" line. I solved it indirectly, by not calling that function so I don't have to bother about the conversion anymore. Thanks for the attention anyway.